# Bean property 'xxx' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I keep getting this error and now I'm not sure why.

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'owner' of bean class [java.util.ArrayList]: Bean property 'owner' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?

I have tried using 
`th:field="*{owner}"`,

`th:field="*{Owner}"`, and

`th:field="*{setOwner}"` but still gets the same error.

Controller

```
@RequestMapping("/wqrms/customer/create")
public String customerCreate(Model model) {
    List<Customer> customer = customerService.listAll();
    model.addAttribute("customer", customer);
    return "/views/wqrms/customer/create";
}
```

Model

```
@Entity
public class Customer {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id;
private String owner;
public long getId() { 
    return id; 
}
public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id; 
}
public String getOwner() { 
    return owner; 
}
public void setOwner(long id) {
    this.owner = owner; 
}
}
```

thymeleaf

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/wqrms/customer/save}" th:object="${customer}" method="post">     
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label>Customer Name</label> 
                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Customer Name" required th:field="*{owner}">
            </div>
```

Comment: The attribute 'customer' is of type List<Customer>, which indeed has no field 'owner'. You probably want to add an 'empty' individual Customer to the model which will then be filled with the setter methods.

Answer (score 1):

you have written the code for getOwner wrongly. The data type of the owner is string and you have declared the method as long.
please rewrite the code to following.

```
public String getOwner() { 
return owner; 
}
```

TIP - Use a IDE while coding, it will help you to figure these compile time errors easily.

Comment: Just used eclipse and generated the getters and setters. I did changed the long to String. That was a typo, but still gets the same error.

Answer (score 1):

You did mistake while creating your Getter & Setter for your Entity class. and How your program compiled successfully. Because inside

```
public long getOwner() { 
    return owner; 
}
```

Method you are using long as a return type but returning String from the getter.
Rewrite your class like this

```
@Entity
public class Customer {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id;
private String owner;

public long getId() { 
    return id; 
}
public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id; 
}
public String getOwner() { 
    return owner; 
}
public void setOwner(String owner) {
    this.owner = owner; 
}
}
```

Or you can choose any IDE ex: Eclipse, IntelliJ for writing the class.

Comment: I did changed the long to String and still gets the same error. I have rewritten the code in eclipse but still no luck.

Comment: After changing the Getter & Setter. Please clean your project once.

Answer (score 0):

Problem fixed! The controller was supposed to be for listing customer. Changed it to

```
`@RequestMapping("/wqrms/customer/create")
 public String customerCreate(Model model) {
     Customer customer = new Customer();
     model.addAttribute("customer", customer);
     return "/views/wqrms/customer/create";
}`
```

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

I cannot give an explanation on how it works but this is what I changed. The getter method I had was `public int getMaximumInv()` I renamed it to `public int getMaximuminv()`. The error disappeared.

Answer (score -1):

**Incorrect getters/setters in POJO.**

*A classic example of why to make code more readable.*

It happens because of unnecessary boiler-plate redundant code.

Use [this-(LOMBOK)](https://www.baeldung.com/intro-to-project-lombok) dependency/jar and all of the code which reduces readability would be removed. 
Lombok is a part of the spring-boot starter as well.

Comment: In my project we are using Lombok @mossad this threat is not about that. Mentioning lombok was good but your answer didn't give a detailed explanation why that is occuring and where it is coming from.. And don't be toxic in stakoverflow :)